# tricks to using Terminal+PowerShell+Vim?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I use Vim evoked in raw PowerShell 7 without problems. I have PowerShell 7 as my shell in Windows Terminal. If I try to evoke Vim in a PowerShell 7 instance withing Terminal, Vim does not behave correctly. (Basic command produce unpredictable results.) Am I missing a trick? (I'm on up to date Win 10, running PowerShell as Admin.)

Comment: Could you clarify - what specific commands/input produces what _specific_ results?

Comment: @zadjii The results are immediately bizarre and utterly unusable. To give just one example, pressing v (enter visual mode) seems to delete a line. So let me turn this around: have you used Vim from Windows Terminal with success, starting Vim from within a Powershell 7 instance in the terminal?

Comment: Yep. I use it pretty regularly whenever I'm working in WSL. My manager uses vim.exe as his default editor of choice - I think if there was an issue with it like what you're describing, that would have been a major ship-blocker 

This might be something to file over at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/new/choose. We might be able to better debug what's up there, rather than in this thread.

Comment: @zadjii Thanks; see [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/15809).

Comment: @zadjii My experience appears to be related to a [known bug in Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14512).

Comment: Oh, so 1.18 fixed it? That's great to hear. That was a particularly gnarly bug - a race condition that manifested itself in a whole bunch of different ways.